# Two circles of equal radius, one "passes over" the other: the intersection area grows and shrinks non-smoothly?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Two circles of equal radius "r" (assume r=1 for simplicity); one "passes over" the other. 
They start by touching, having an empty intersection, and then slowly the intersection grows, until the circles are on top of each other. In that case, the intersection area is of course equal to the area of the unit circle (r=1). As the circle moves on after that, it shrinks again.

If I follow the formula in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html where x is the "width" of the intersection area, I get:

[image: Graph as the circle passes over the other, until it becomes one with it]

Well this is kind of unexpected isn't it? That means, if the circle starts moving away again, because of the symmetry of the problem, it starts shrinking with the mirror of this graph. But, that leaves it with a spike at the top of the graph?! Meaning, the intersection area grows and shrinks in a non-smooth manner?

Did anyone expect this to happen? Did I make an error when calculating?

Comment: The area varies continuously.

Comment: Indeed I meant non-smoothly, I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area changes continuously, you just get a pointy bit at the top of the graph.

Perhaps you meant that the graph isn't differentiable at the top? That's true: if you think about it, the area is going up very fast "just before" the circles are coincident, but just afterwards, the area goes down very quickly. This means that the graph is not differentiable at the point where the circles are coincident. Intuitively, as you approach coincident circles, the derivative approaches adding infinitesimal semicircles, followed by immediately subtracting them once you cross.

Comment: Yes I meant it is not differentiable. It's not "smooth", I'll correct the post as I used a bad term (not a maths expert)

Comment: By the way I discovered that as soon as the "passing" circle is a little more ellipsoid (squashed just a tiny fraction in y direction), the curve grows smoother on the top - I'm not sure if it becomes differentiable and at what point of squashing, yet.